# How to reboot the system automatically when it freezes

Tags: linux, debian

I work at a bank and we've been dealing with a problem: our cash machines freeze all the time, and everytime they freeze we need to reset it so it goes back to normal. But right now we are doing it manually, so we spend the whole day monitoring the cash machines using a remote access software, and everytime we see a frozen ATM, we reboot it remotely. Doing this all day can be very stressfull and tiring, so the question is: is there any way to program the system to reboot everytime the ATM software freezes? The OS is Linux/Debian.

Comment: To clarify: the software freezes, but the system is still responsive? Maybe also go into more detail about how "frozen" is defined.

Comment: why do you believe that the bank would allow you to reprogram the system?

Comment: What surprises me the most is that this would be the job of a watchdog and I just cannot imagine cash dispensers not embedding (at least) one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: How exactly do you detect a frozen ATM? How exactly do you reboot it automatically? I guess this could be written as a script, and you could use `cron` to run the script repeatedly.

Comment: Guys, to make it clear: we detect a frozen ATM by acessing it remotely. We simply use VNC viewer to see if the ATM is Ok or not. When its frozen, we reset it remotely using another software called Putty. The problem is that we need to spend all day monitoring the ATM's to detect when some of them freeze. Of course thats not a very efficient solution, which is why we are looking for alternatives.

Comment: I think you're going about the problem wrong. The systems should not be freezing unless there is a software misconfiguration or if it is not handling inputs well. You need to find out why the freeze is happening and and fix the root problem.

Comment: Such freezes may and do lead to data/productivity loss, so if your devices are not thin terminals, I'd try to get to the root of the issue instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I did meet a frozen linux for reason:

- hardware problem (failling RAM module, harddisk, PCI card)
- incompatible kernel modules, bad compiled kernel
- hacking intrusion

For diagnostic I usually let open SSH server to test if the system is really frozen.

The device you need is called **watch-dog**.
Such device is usually connected to a serial port (or any other simple signal line), and its deal is to wait for periodical receive a simple signal - e.g. it expects to receive each minute a single string: "OK(CR)". If such signal does not come the device pull the reset pin of the CPU chip.
The system must each minute send the string. Such behaviour can be configured with `cron` , but for various reason, the system may not catch it in time. Task which are not time synchronised, can be lately completed by `anacron` but it is not possible with watch-dog. For that purpose it is better to use RT kernel or set carefully the watch-dog period. (Set the device to wait 5 min, but the system to send each 2 min)

Anyway, it is not simply software solution.

My advice is: check the system first, make a quite new installation and save it as a disk image (for better and quicker restore, and for later comparison with a broken system), keep your accounting subnet more secure (use a private address range, isolate it with NAT, firewall . . .); build a logging server in such subnet and configure your linux boxes to send its logs to it.

Simply make your system more robust, secure and verbose.